# How to simulate nonstoparagraphing in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting

Long ago, some weirdos called "Science Fiction Fans" invented an alternate paragraph format: nonstoparagraphing.  In this format, when you reached the end of a paragraph, you would reach up and turn the knob down one space, but not move the carriage. 
                                                                      The result provided about the same visual separation between paragraphs as option 1, but didn't waste all that space at the end of the line.

```
I'm prepping a document that uses nonstoparagraphing for the web.
                                                                   This is easy 
to do in its current format (Word document).  Also works if turned into a PDF.  
But the obvious solution (add a bunch of NBSPs to the start of the lines) will 
break in a web browser if the user has changed the default font or even the 
font size.  
           Can anybody think of a way to get this effect, more-or-less reliably, 
in HTML and CSS?  (I'm willing to use Javascript too.)
```

Comment: Why am I trying to do this? You may ask.  The original material was typed that way (on Ditto(R) masters) and I'd like to present it as close as possible to the original format.

Comment: I'll just ask, *what* you are trying to do, because your description isn't descriptive enough. Later on, you can answer *why*.

Comment: Illustrate the effect in a monospaced code block, if you can.  I honestly haven't the slightest idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I can't quite visualize it, although an explanation on the internet did help "the following paragraph begins one line down and two spaces past the last character in the last line of the preceding paragraph." Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sherriffderek, Robert Harvey: What I'm trying to do was shown in my first comment.

Derek: Yes, exactly.

In any case, the answer from Daze is great, it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this quickly and it's not a complete solution, but someone else can improve on my answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/rJ22T/

```
p {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;}
p + p {top: 1em;}
p + p + p {top: 2em;}
```

Basically, display the paragraphs as inline elements, then add an incremental vertical shift. Some javascript should be able to automate this.

**Addendum:** As per the comments, we need to account for the elements that follow. Place all the `<p>` elements within a `<div>`, then add this to the CSS:

```
p:last-child:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
}
```

Here, `4em` would be equal to the last `top` paragraph shift, plus whatever extra spacing you need.

**Addendum 2:** Another example with more content here: http://jsfiddle.net/rJ22T/3/

Comment: I like it!  I'm going to try it and see how it works.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Don't even need javascript, just make sure I have enough of those to do the job.  And add some space at the end, otherwise the last paragraph (or two) will overlap whatever comes after.

I love tasteful and elegant solutions.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about the elements that would follow. Here's how I fixed that: `p:last-child:after {content:"";display:block;margin-bottom:4em;}`. See the addendum on my answer for details.

Comment: The last-child-after would work if all my nonstoparagraphing sequences had exactly 4 paragraphs.

Comment: I think I'll just wrap the whole thing in a <div> and add a sufficient number of <br>s at the end.  Or add style="margin-bottom: xem;" to the last paragraph of the NSP sequence.